# how to send array in http or dio request using form data in flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart, dio

I am sending form data to the api. Here is an image of the following pattern. How i will do this in flutter [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aSwN.png)

Comment: You can add all your key in a loop, the key will be the same as your postman image.
Ex.- 'vt_dates[0]' this will be your key for the first index.